# Assign value to data frame in R to all elements conditionally

Tags: r

I try to assign value to all cells in a dataframe having a specific value
by this code

```
train_data <- read.csv("train_set.csv",header=TRUE)
train_data[train_data == "<NA>"] <- 0
```

But it does not work, I still see the values unchanged. How can I change  values? Data in CSV is as below

```
spec1   spec2
NA      NA  
NA      NA  
NA      NA  
NA      NA  
NA      NA  
NA      NA  
NA      NA  
NA      NA  
SP-0013 SP-0063     
SP-0013 SP-0063     
NA      NA
NA      NA
NA      NA
NA      NA
NA      NA
NA      NA
```

Comment: Try `train_data[is.na(train_data)] <- 0`  assuming that NA are real NAs.  Also, it is better to read with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`  in the `read.csv`

Comment: `train` vs `train_data`?

Comment: A reproducible example would also be helpful - supply some dummy data

Comment: Data sample is added

Comment: @akrun: your suggestion did not work. I still see <NA> when data frame is printed

Comment: As ds440 suggested, you may need to post a dput output of a small example data i..e `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))`.  It should work in normal cases as I was able to get the correct output from your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akrun and others have mentioned we may need an actual copy of your data, but give this a shot:

```
train_data <- read.csv("train_set.csv", header=TRUE, na.strings = c("NA", "<NA>"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

train_data[is.na(train_data)] <- 0
```